# Get field value by name

Tags: jquery

I have the following input field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="field_tab_order[0]" />
```

How to access this using name attribute with jQuery. This must be easy. I am having trouble trying to access it like this:

> ```
> jQuery('input[name=field_tab_order[0]]');
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

must quote

```
jQuery('input[name="field_tab_order[0]"]');
```

or escape

```
jQuery('input[name=field_tab_order\\[0\\]]');
```

when using certain characters in selector

Because jQuery uses CSS syntax for selecting elements, some characters are interpreted as CSS notation.

For example, periods, colons, braces etc. are problematic within the context of a jQuery selector because they indicate another atttribute selector nested in the first etc.

In order to tell jQuery to treat these characters literally rather than as CSS notation, they must be "escaped" by placing two backslashes in front of them.

Comment: oh! thnx...it was really that simple..by the way don't we use single slash(\) for escaping?

Comment: It's a string literal, which will later be passed to something else in jQuery, so we'll need double escaping.

Comment: @adeneo when to use single and when to use double escape?

Comment: In a jQuery selector, always use two slashes.

Comment: if we have a control id like "someid.somestring" then?? ``$("#someid\\."somestring")``, is it correct?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - Yes, that is correct, always two slashes.

Answer (score 2):

you have to put quotes for name attribute value like this:

```
jQuery('input[name="field_tab_order[0]"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var value =  $('input[name="field_tab_order[0]"]').val();
```